# Is it possible to Create 2Topics with same partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

My Requirement is to Create 2 topics with same partition and if i produce messages to two different topics data can store in only one partition.
Is it Possible to create 2 Topics with Same Partition?

To acheive **Multi-Tenancy**, for example, multiple tenants are (Tenant-1, Tenant-2), For each Tenant, we have their specific Topics.

```
Tenant-1 ---> has Topic1, Topic2, Topic3
Tenant-2 ---> has Topic4, Topic5.
```

Looking to keep these Tenant specific data with in their single partition.
that is,

```
Topics1,2,3(records) ---> in partition-0, and Topics4,5(records) in partition-1
```

Is this possible, or what could be the best way to approach it..!

Comment: No, you can't do anything like that

Comment: This is not possible. What is your requirement? Please explain your requirement, may be possible to solve it other way.

Comment: @chinna can you explain why do you need two topics here? what benefits are you expecting with this requirement?

Comment: I am editing my question for more clarity, please take a look in to it..

Comment: No, you cannot do that.The topic can be divided into many partitions. You can have many topics with the same partition numbers, but their data is not stored together in the 1 partition. About your multi-tenancy, how about creating topic for the same business for all tenants and partition the data based on the tenant id?

Comment: What can we do, if tenant has verticals to be handled, so partition, cannot be split , as it is atomic for a Topic..

Comment: To achieve multi Tenancy why you want to divide it based on partitions. When you can consume the multiple topics. You can insert into multiple topics and then can consume multiple topics as well.

Answer (score 0):

Having same partition for more than 1 topics is not possible in Kafka(even it is not possible in any system, IMO). The only major benefit you get from this approach is ordered data.

If you are not bothered about order of the data, then you can always have multiple topics per tenant and you can always consume from all those topics at the same time.

Hope this helps!